# Let $P(X_n=n)=1/n^a$ and zero otherwise. Let $Y_n=X_{n+1}\cdot X_n$. Find all $a$ such that $\liminf Y_n=0$ and $\limsup Y_n=\infty$ almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, borel-cantelli-lemmas

*Remark:* My attemps is WRONG as I fasly assumed that the $Y_n$ were independant. I ve corrected this in my own answer to this post. This answer is correct but not enough well wrotten, read the selected answer for a better quality answer.

### Question:

Let $a > 0$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let the random variable $X_n$ on $\{0,n\}$ be defined by
$$
\begin{cases}
P(X_n=0)=1- \frac{1}{n^{a}}\\
P(X_n=n)=\frac{1}{n^{a}}.
\end{cases}
$$
All $X_n$ are independent. Define the random variables $Y_n=X_{n+1}\cdot X_n$.

> Find the set of all $a$ such that
> $$P(\omega \in \Omega: \liminf_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = 0 \cap \limsup_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = \infty) = 1.$$

### Attempt:

I have already proved the following statement.

#### Part 1

Let's denote
$$ D = \{ \omega \in \Omega : Y_n(\omega) \neq 0 \text{ for infinity many } n \}.$$

In order for $Y_n(\omega) \neq 0 $ we should have both $ X_n(\omega) \neq 0, X_{n+1} (\omega) \neq 0$, so
$$P(Y_n \neq 0 ) = P(X_n\neq 0 \cap X_{n+1}  \neq 0 ) = \frac{1}{n^a} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^a}.$$

Hence according to the Borel-Cantelli lemma we have that
$$P(D)= 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n \geq 1} P(Y_n \neq 0) =  \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^a} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^a} < \infty $$
and this occurs if and only if $a > \frac{1}{2}$.

We also have that
$$P(D)= 1 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n \geq 1} P(Y_n \neq 0) =  \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^a} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^a} = \infty $$
and this occurs if and only if $0 < a \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

#### Part 2

Let's denote
$$E = \{ \omega \in \Omega : Y_n(\omega) = 0 \text{ for infinitely many } n\}.$$

In order for $Y_n(\omega) = 0 $ we should have at least one $ X_n(\omega) = 0$ and/or $ X_{n+1} (\omega) = 0 $. Hence we have that
$$P(Y_n = 0 ) = 1-P(X_n\neq 0 \cap X_{n+1}  \neq 0 ) = 1 - \frac{1}{n^a} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^a}.$$

Hence according to the Borel-Cantelli lemma we have that
$$P(E)= 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n \geq 1} P(Y_n \neq 0) =  \sum_{n \geq 1} 1 - \frac{1}{n^a} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^a} < \infty $$
and this never occurs for any $a > 0$.

In other words we have that have that for any $a>0$ we have
$$P(E)= 1 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n \geq 1} P(Y_n = 0) =  \sum_{n \geq 1}  1- \frac{1}{n^a} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^a} = \infty. $$

Indeed in order for a series $\sum_{n \geq 1 } a_n $ to be convergent we require $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ but here obviously $a_n= 1- \frac{1}{n^a} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^a} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 1 \neq 0$ for any $a>0$ so the series is necessary divergent.

#### Part 3

3- We can note that the event $\limsup_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = \infty$ is equivalent to the event $D$ and that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = 0$ is equivalent to the event $E$. So we can reformulate the question as follows:

> For which $a>0$ do we have that the probability that we get infinitely often $Y_n \neq 0 $ and at the same time that we get $Y_n = 0$ happens too infinitely often at the same time.

Moreover according to **Part 2** we have that $D \subseteq E$ as the event $E$ is always realized when we repeat our experience an infinity of times. And it is only the event $D$ that may not be realized if we repeat our experience an infinity of times.

Thus
$$P(\omega \in \Omega: \liminf_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = 0 \cap \limsup_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = \infty) = P(\omega \in \Omega: \limsup_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = \infty) = P(D) = 1 $$ for  $0<a \leq \frac{1}{2}$ according to **Part 1**.

Is this correct? I have mostly doubt on my **Part 3**.
Thank for your help.

Comment: up anyone to help me?

Comment: Anyone to tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: "$D\subseteq E$" is incorrect. Part 2 gives you that $P(E)=1$. That does not mean all sets are now subsets of $E$.

Comment: Why my question has been down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be much more compact and precise in writing your answer. Let $i.o.$ stand for infinitely often.

Let $D=\{\omega:Y_{n}(\omega)=0\,\,i.o.\}$ and let $E=\{\omega:Y_{n}\neq 0\,\,i.o.\}$

The obvious case of $a=0$ is ommitted.

If $a>\frac{1}{2}$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|Y_{n}|>\epsilon)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{a}(n+1)^{a}}<\infty$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Hence by Borel-Cantelli Lemma 1, you have that $Y_{n}$ converges to $0$ almost surely and hence $\lim\sup Y_{n}=\lim\inf Y_{n}=0$ almost surely.

So consider $0<a\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Note that the sequence $(Y_{2n})_{n\geq 3}$ is a sequence of independent random variables. Now, you have $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}P(Y_{2n}=2n(2n+2))=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(2n(2n+1))^{a}}=\infty$$

and hence by Borel-Cantelli Lemma 2, you have that $P(\{Y_{n}=2n(2n+2)\,\,i.o.\})=1$. As $\{Y_{n}=2n(2n+2)\,\,i.o.\}\subset E$, you have that $P(E)=1$.

And $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(Y_{n}=0)=\infty\implies P(D)=1$ again due to Borel Cantelli Lemma 2.

Hence $P(D\cap E)=1$ which means that almost surely $\lim\sup Y_{n}=\infty$ and $\lim\inf Y_{n}=0$. That is, for each $\omega\in D\cap E$, you have $\lim\sup Y_{n}(\omega)=\infty$ and $\lim\inf Y_{n}(\omega)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. You re right but I am happy to learn that my reasoning in the answer was correct.

Comment: @OffHakhol Well, I said you got the main trick of the problem correctly. But there were many mistakes in your reasoning. For example, you wrote "$D\subseteq E$". That is simply wrong. What you want is simply that $D\cap E$ to be of measure $1$. For example, your random variables can be constructed in such a way such that $\Omega=[0,1]$ and  $D=\{\text{irrationals in} [0,1]\}$ and $E=\{\text{irrationals in [0,1]}\}\setminus\{\pi/4\}$. Then neither is $E\subseteq D$ nor is $D\subseteq E$. But still $P(D\cap E)=1$ which is what is required.

Comment: Ok but what I can't say that $D \subseteq E$ a.s.? indeed if $P(D \cap E) = 1$ why i do not have $D \cap E = \Omega $ a.s. ?

Comment: @OffHakhol Because it does not make any sense. Set inclusion or equality is not something that you compare by measure. The sets are not Random here so what is it that you are at all comparing with an equality here? Again and again I am repeating the same thing. Almost sure equality/inequality should be a statement about random variables and not deterministic sets.

Answer (score 0):

I thought again on this question and on my answer and I have found that it is incorrect for different reasons (one of them is that I ve used incorrectly the BC lemma ). So below you will be able to read a new (and I think and hope correct) answer of mine.

#### Answer:

1- According to the answer I ve posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4877790/y-n-x-n1x-n-withx-n-i-i-dr-v-defined-px-n-0-1-px-n-n-px-n-n-fr) we have that $P(D) = 1$ with $D =  \{ Y_n(\omega) \neq 0  $ for an infinity of indexes $n \in \{1,2,3,.... \}  \} $ for  $0  < a \leq \frac{1}{2} $.
Moreover it is easy to notice that $ P(limsup Y_n = \infty) $ correspond to the probability of $P(D)$ as the event $ D $ and $\{ \omega \in \Omega : limsup_ {n \to \infty }Y_n = \infty \} $ are a.s. equals.

2- Now let's focus on the event $ E= \{ ω∈Ω:Y_n(ω)=0 $  for infinitely many $ n \}. $  that correspond to the event $ \{\omega \in \Omega : \liminf _{n \to \infty }  Y_n = 0 \}$
We want to prove that $P(E)=1 , \forall a>0$ that will mean that $ E = \Omega$ a.s.
But again here we can not use directly BC lemma as the sequence of events $ \{ A_k \} = \{Y_k = 0 \}$ are not independent,but we can note that $P(A_k) = 1 - P(\{Y_k \neq 0 \})  = 1 - (\frac{1}{n(n+1)})^a$
So let focus on the following set $ E_{even}= \{ ω∈Ω:Y_{2n}(ω)=0 $  for infinitely many $ n \} $ and on the following sequence of events $ \{ A_{2k} \} = \{Y_{2k} = 0 \} $. That are independant (trivial) thus we can use the corresponding BC lemma and we get that $P(E_{even})=1$ because $ \sum_{n>0} P(A_{2n}) = \sum_{n>0} 1 - (\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)})^a = \infty $ as the necessary condition of convergence for serie is not even respected, indeed $1 - (\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)})^a \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 1 \neq 0$
Obviously $ E_{even} \subseteq E \Rightarrow P(E_{even}) = 1$ thus for any $a>0$ we necessarly have  $P(E)=1$ and $\Omega = E $ a.s.

3- Combining "1-" and "2-" we have that $ D \cap E = D$ a.s. and so that $P(D \cap E ) = P(D) $ thus $ P(D \cap E )=1 $ for $ 0< a \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: up. Anyone to tell me if it is correst?

Comment: Since you are considering $A_{2k}$, it seems to me that you have got the main trick of the problem correct. Now don't take it the wrong way but your writing is extremely hard to follow and the answer is poorly written. You can be way more compact and accurate by just showing that $P(D)=1$ and $P(E)=1$ when $0<a\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Also, statements like $\Omega=E$ a.s. make no sense. They are sets and not random variables. Just writing $P(E)=1$ suffices.

Comment: Neither does statements like $D$ and $\{\omega:\lim\sup Y_{n}=\infty\}$ are equal a.s. No these two sets are equal and that's it. You talk about almost sure equality for random variables. Also, if two sets have probability $1$, it does not mean they are equal.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thank you for your precision. But why if a set has a measure of $1$ why I can't say that this set is a.s. equal to the set $\Omega$ that from our probability space $(\Omega ; \sigma(\Omega) ) $

Comment: @OffHakol because such a statement does not even make any sense and is unheard off. Firstly, equality of sets means that the elements of both the sets are same. So almost sure equality does not make any sense here. What is it that you are at all comparing? When one says that $X=Y$ almost surely, then it means that $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in A$ where $A$ is some set with measure $1$. In case of sets, what does even $A=B$ a.s. mean? Are the sets themselves random (this is possible, eg, Poisson Point Process) ? In your case no. Instead just write $P(E)=1$ because only this is true.